# How to call Javascript Variable in MVC Controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This is my current code. My `imageData` in the controller does not receive anything when I click the button. But when I use `document.write(images);` in javascript and remove `$("#btnSave")` to show if there is a value it shows `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE....` this is what i need to pass to controller to save the image right? I think there is something wrong in my javascript to pass the value in the controller.

**VIEW**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SampleCaptureImage", "Warehouse", FormMethod.Post))
{
      <canvas id="canvas" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
      <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" id="btnSave" value="Save Drawing" />
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        var images = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
        images = images.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        $.post(
                '@Url.Action("SampleCaptureImage","Warehouse")',
                { imageData: images },
                handleSuccess
            );
    });
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult SampleCaptureImage(string imageData)
{
      string fileName = "CapturedImage.png";
      string fileNameWitPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Sanipex Captured Images"), fileName);

      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
      {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                 byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                 bw.Write(data);
                 bw.Close();
             }
             fs.Close();
      }
      return view();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you using submit button, it will go for the default way instead of the ajax that you using

either add preventDefault() or change your button type to `button`

you can read more about preventDefault(), http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

is the script inline or js file?

try

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var images = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
        images = images.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        //$.post(
                //'@Url.Action("SampleCaptureImage","Warehouse")',
               // { imageData: images },
             //   handleSuccess
        //    );
       $.post('@Url.Action("SampleCaptureImage","Warehouse")', { imageData: images })
        .done(function( data ) {
          alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });

    });
```

Comment: nothind change in the result it is still null value.

Comment: it is exactly what you did.

Comment: no error. i din't change button type to button because it will not go to controller. you said add preventdefault OR change type to button. right?

Comment: No, if your ajax is correct, then the `type button` will definitely go into your controller without preventDefault, unless your ajax is wrong, put a breakpoint in your controller and and see if it go to your controller?

Comment: it does not go to my controller

Comment: thats mean your ajax have issue here, your code is inline? @Url.Action("SampleCaptureImage","Warehouse") is mvc method, if your script is not inline code, it wont read correctly

Comment: what do you mean by inline script? my script and html are inside 1 VIEW

Comment: Inline mean thats your write your script in your view, hmmm, now is getting tricky, have you actually use web debugger tools before? Press f12(google chrome), go to network tab, click the save button, and check the new item appear(might be in red color), and click it see what it actually write

Comment: i don't see save button but i found 1 result red color jquery.min.map i think this is not part of it?

Comment: click your btnSave, and watch the new item appear in the network tab, the min.map is not an issue here

Comment: at the debugger tools, can you see a red dot with a cross at the right side of the debugger tools? if have, click it, a console will appear from bottom and list out the error

Comment: i don't have debugger tool. do you have skype or something so we can talk :) i am not allowed to chat here :D

Comment: the debugger tools is the 1 that I ask you to press(f12) thats the free debugger tools that come together with google chrome and firefox

Comment: found it. "Uncaught reference error: $ is not define" it is pointing at "$("#btnSave").click(function () "

Comment: $ error mean that is jquery issue here, have u included your jquery? by the way, check this link to ease your troubleshoot in the future, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index

Comment: include in your view that need jquery, or MasterPage, MasterView etc
<Scrip src ="your jquery here"></script>

Comment: it is not on my Layout page(masterpage) what jquerry should i include?

Comment: whatever jquery plugin you had

Comment: the error change. something is wrong in here. "var url= '/Warehouse/CaptureImage'
        $.post(url,{ imageData: images },
                function (data) {
                });"

Answer (score 0):

Your controller SampleCaptureImage does not have a HttpPost attribute, and it will only receive HTTP GET requests by default.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider another way to submit the form instead of using a submit type of button.  You can do a regular button like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SampleCaptureImage","Warehouse", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SubmitForm"}))
{
    <a href="#" id="SubmitBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Submit</a>
}
```

Then in javascript, do this:

```
$("#SubmitBtn").click(function ()
{
    $("#SubmitForm").submit();
});
```

And in the click() function, could do any other special work before the submit.

Comment: it does not go to my controller. just postback the page